# ATLAS gemm linking undefined reference to 'cblas_sgemm'

Tags: c++, c, blas, atlas

This is the first time I am trying to use ATLAS. I am not able to link it properly. Here is a very simple sgemm program:

```
...
#include <cblas.h>


const int M=10;
const int N=8;
const int K=5;

int main()
{
    float *A = new float[M*K];
    float *B = new float[K*N];
    float *C = new float[M*N];

    // Initialize A and B

    cblas_sgemm(CblasRowMajor, CblasNoTrans, CblasNoTrans, M, N, K, 1.0, A, K, B, N, 0.0, C, N);

        ...
}
```

When I compile it on a linux platform with standard ATLAS installation, it gives linking error:

```
g++ test.c -lblas -lcblas -latlas -llapack
/tmp/cc1Gu7sr.o: In function `main':
test.c:(.text+0x29e): undefined reference to `cblas_sgemm(CBLAS_ORDER, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, CBLAS_TRANSPOSE, int, int, int, float, float const*, int, float const*, int, float, float*, int)'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

As you can see, I have tried giving different combination of libraries but didn't help. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need

```
extern "C"
{
   #include <cblas.h>
}
```

because you compile with `g++`.

Or you could even do

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif
   #include <cblas.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

to be able to compile as C also.

When you compile in C++, names are expected to be mangled. But since cblas is compiled in C, the exported symbols don't have mangled names. So you have to instruct the compiler to look for C-style symbols.

Comment: Likely to be the case, but I'm surprised that `<cblas.h>` doesn't already have this guard.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't thought about that as its quite common to have this guard now a days in libraries. Anyways, just doing extern "C" made it work.

Comment: This solution is needed also when using ``AMD-BLIS`` (the blas library of AMD) inside a program compiled with ``g++``. One needs to use the ``extern`` keyword when including ``"cblas.h"``, otherwise a link-time error (no references to function ...) appears !

Answer (score 2):

Be careful about the code. It's "C", not C.
So, the code finally is

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif //__cplusplus
   #include <cblas.h>
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif //__cplusplus
```